# Is there a way to tell how many of a certain Pokemon I have caught?

Tags: pokemon-go

As some Pokemon are more likely to exist in some areas and environments than others, most users end up capturing a lot of the same kind. For example, I have a lot of Drowzee's in my area, most I'll end up transferring for candies.

The medals will show you how many Pokemon of a certain type I've caught (bug, ice, ground, etc,). But
is there any way to see the total number of any one Pokemon that I've caught?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Yes!**

This is available under your Pokedex, or Pokemon Index.

Click the Pokeball at the bottom of your screen, choose Pokedex, then select a Pokemon:

[image]

But the caveat is you **also** see how many you've let escape :-)

Comment: answering yourself lol

Comment: yeah i know is a feature but i lol anyway. thanks for explaining how, i didnt even thing about the possibility

Comment: i lol about 115 drowzees ^^ have the same amount of pidgeys.